# How to ensure an argument is like a NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function that is designed to take an argument `a` that is a NumPy array, but I would like it to also gracefully work with other `array_like` types. That includes a `float`, treated as a 0-dimensional array, a list of numbers, treated as a 1-dimensional array, etc.

A simple way to ensure that is to convert it to a NumPy array, e.g. by

```py
a = np.asanyarray(a)
```

The drawback is that `asanyarray` also converts objects that already work like NumPy arrays out of the box, like Dask arrays and CuPy arrays, where conversion is unnecessary because my code would work with the original object, and detrimental because it destroys the benefits of these objects (parallel / GPU computation).

Is there a function or method that returns anything unchanged that walks or quacks like a NumPy array, but converts everything else into an `np.ndarray`?

Comment: `isinstance(your_object, np.ndarray)` ? `isinstance(your_object, float)`, `isinstance(your_object, int)`

Comment: @Epsi95, that might be the way to implement this myself, I'm asking whether it already exists. I can't be the first person needing this.

Comment: How about looking for some attribute/method like `obj.__array__()`.  Release notes talk about array protocols like this, but I haven't paid much attention to them (I'm not a Dask or CuPy user).  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.20.0-notes.html?highlight=array_like#arraylike-objects-which-do-not-define-len-and-getitem.  `numpy` "knows" about things that are 'below', like list and scalars, but not things 'above'.

Comment: @hpaulj, yes, I read about "array protocols". I'm just not sure whether to check for `__array__` or `__array_function__`, ...

Comment: If you are already using Dask or other packages, then you are in better position to test alternatives.  You probably know your way around their documentation.

Comment: This is not about Dask, but about NumPy's protocols. And yes, I've read them, but I don't understand them.

Comment: Not currently an answer, but perhaps in the future: https://data-apis.org/array-api/latest/ and https://numpy.org/neps/nep-0047-array-api-standard.html "if they want to support multiple kinds of arrays, check if the incoming array object supports the array API standard by checking for ``__array_namespace__``"

Answer (score 1):

The function I'm looking for doesn't seem to exist, and I ended up creating my own implementation, which relies on the presence of `__array_function__`.

It seems to work, but I'm not 100% sure it will work for all cases. Input from the NumPy developers would be useful.

```py
def duckarray(x):
    """Ensure an argument walks and quacks like an array.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : array_like
        Something array-like.

    Returns
    -------
    array_like
        Something that walks and quacks like an array.

    Notes
    -----
    Checks whether `x` supports the NumPy `__array_function__` protocol,
    returns it unchanged if yes, and converts it via `np.asanyarray` if not.
    """
    if hasattr(x, '__array_function__'):
        return x
    else:
        return np.asanyarray(x)
```